# How do I sort a Python list of strftime('%I:%M %p') in django templates?

Tags: python, time, django-templates, sorting

I have a python list of time values. I have the list in the following format. How would I sort the time values in ascending order?

```
timeSlot = [
    {'timeSlot': '1:15 PM'},
    {'timeSlot': '9:15 PM'},
    {'timeSlot': '9:15 AM'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> timeSlot.sort(key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d['timeSlot'], '%I:%M %p'))
>>> timeSlot
[{'timeSlot': '9:15 AM'}, {'timeSlot': '1:15 PM'}, {'timeSlot': '9:15 PM'}]
```